# Super Search returns no results with category parameter

Tags: supersearch

I'm trying to filter results to a few channels and I want to exclude entries in the news channel with the category of "Internal News". The following returns no results.

```
{exp:super_search:results 
    channel="not blog|breakouts|calendar|work|heros" sort_by="asc"
    limit="15"
    status="open"
    category="-Internal News"
    relevance="title=500+summary=10+body=2" 
    relevance_proximity="yes"
    highlight_keywords="strong"
    smart_excerpt="yes"}
...
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

I've tried category="-internal-news" and I've tried the category filter in the search form with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried removing as many parameters as possible to see if that makes a difference (eg. smart_excerpt, highlight_keywords, relevance, relevance_proximity, limit)? The less parameters, the closer we are to isolating the problem. Also, `sort_by=""` is not a valid parameter.

Comment: Another note here to mention that the main poster is using Super Search 2.1.3 on EE 2.7

Comment: I removed everything down until it was just the category parameter and It still returns 0 results for any search term.
{exp:super_search:results category="-Internal News"}

Answer (score 1):

Have you played with the `category_indicator=` parameter to make sure it's matching the way you are indicating your categories? I find it's always much more robust when using category url titles.

Comment: Maybe try quotes around the category name because it's multiple words? I find things can get messy if you allow spaces so it might be worth switching to category url titles instead.